# Optional parameters: constants vs direct declaration in method?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, constants, optional-parameters

What is the better approach for methods with optional parameters:

1. **Declare constant and use it as default parameter:**

[image]

2. **Or declare default parameters in method:**

[image]

I'm sorry for images instead of code but WYSIWYG editor is buggy.

Comment: Whichever you want.  The code is functionally identical.  It's purely a user preference.

Comment: `WYSIWYG editor is buggy` - No it's not. You may not how to use it properly?

Comment: Declaring constants is generally better practice.  It gives you access to those default values for use in other handling, etc.  This is probably treading on the 'soliciting opinion' side of question asking, however...

Comment: @HighCore i used it many times on stackoverflow but in this post it don't want to recognize my code. I tried many times.

Comment: Just *never* change the defaults. That would make people unhappy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a matter of personal preference.  The two will be basically identical.

`const` may have an advantage in many cases, however.  If you use the value in more than one location in the code, I would prefer the `const` declaration instead of specifying inline, as you don't repeat the value, and it makes it simpler to check (and potentially change later), as it's kept in one place.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference whatsoever to the IL that's produced, as others have already pointed out.

I want to make a tangential point about using default parameters:

Because they are compiled-in to the software, changing them after you've released software can cause bugs. You can wind up with different software components using different defaults.

It's much better (if you can) to use a special "default value" indicator. Then inside the method, you detect such special values and substitute the appropriate default value. That way you can change the default in future versions much more reliably.

For example, for your CreateApple() example, you could do something like this:

```
static Apple CreateApple(string size = "<<default>>", string colour = "<<default>>")
{
    if (size == "<<default>>")
        size = "Big";

    if (colour == "<<default>>")
        colour = "Red";
```

I think in this case you should be using enums - but the same still applies for enums and other types. As long as you have a value which doesn't fall into the valid normal range for that parameter, you can use it to indicate "default".

Answer (score -1):

Can place defaults in the class.
It has the benefit of being enforced at the class.
And apparent to anyone reading the class.

```
public class Apple
{
    private string size  = "big";
    private string color = "red";
    public string  Size  { get { return size; }  set { size  = value; } } 
    public string  Color { get { return color; } set { color = value; } }
    public Apple() 
    { } // for private as default 
    public Apple(string Size, string Color) 
    { size = Size; color = Color; }   // if you don't want the private defaults
}
```

If you wanted the default for one but not the other

```
Apple apple = new Apple("small", (new Apple()).Color);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all...

Comment: @Servy that is your opinion and got to make it with a -1.

Comment: This isn't even showing any optional arguments to a constructor, not could you use either of these members as the optional argument for a constructor as they aren't compile time constants.  There's nothing opinion about it; this in no way answers the question.

Comment: The OP omitted constructors.  And I omitted constructor also.  So you disagree.  That is how I handle defaults.

Comment: Sorry, it's not just constructors, it's any optional arguments.  In any case, you still couldn't use either of these as the default value for optional arguments as they aren't compile time constants.  You also don't explain the difference between the two approaches the OP lists, which is what the actual question is, nor do you explain how your "solution" is better than either (or even how it works, because I assert it doesn't).  There's some opinion mixed in there, but by and large it's objective fact.

Comment: But I would just call the empty ctor if I want the defaults.  I will clarify.

Comment: Note that not all methods create a POCO.  If the arguments are used to do something other than set a property/field then this technique can't work.  Sometimes it's also important to have the *option* of using the constructor rather than being forced to create a default object and mutating it; your option removes that functionality.

Comment: The question does not indication the arguments are used for anything but setting a property/field.  It is an approach not listed.  It has the benefit of encapsulating the default in the class.

Comment: It specifies method*s* with optional arguments, not just that one exact example.  Also, creating two objects just so you can have one default argument instead of two...that's also a pretty messy way of solving the problem.  Hardly an improvement in my eyes.  Also, you haven't explained in what way this option is superior to either of the OP's solutions.  I only see ways in which it's inferior.

Comment: I don't proclaim it is superior. It is presented as another option. You make it clear a long time ago you did not feel it was a good option.  Let it go.